# MVC TextBoxFor selected value

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I don't use `DropDownListFor`,without `DropDownListFor`..
I want use `TextBoxFor` because my `TextBoxFor` contain autodata,
With save `TextBoxFor` value 0 in my database..How I get selected value and save values my database ..for help thanks
 Code:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model=>model.Fakulteler,new {@type="text",@class="form-control",id= "FakultelerId"})
```

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#FakultelerId").autocomplete({
            source: '@Url.Action("Search","Fakulte")'
        });
    });
</script>
```

Code:

```
public List<string> Search(string name)
{
    KutuphaneContext db = new DataContext.KutuphaneContext();
    return db.Fakulte.Where(x => x.FakulteAdi.Contains(name)).Select(x => x.FakulteAdi).ToList();
}

public ActionResult Search(string term)
{
    Fakulte fak = new Models.Fakulte();
    return Json(fak.Search(term), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: Bind the `blur` event on the textbox and pass the inputed data using josn?

Comment: No Cristian , please example

Comment: Why? I m not answer my questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the autocomplete change event to save the selected data:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#FakultelerId").autocomplete({
            source: '@Url.Action("Search","Fakulte")',
            change: function( event, ui ) {
                if (ui.item !== null) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '/Search/SaveData',
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: { Value: ui.item.value },
                        success: function (data) {
                            // do something after saving
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

And you will have your method:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult SaveData(string Value)
{
    // Do something with data
    return Json(true);
}
```

The `change` event will be triggered only if the selected value has changed.

Comment: Thank You Cristian